# Logo in footer with aligned text

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to create a latex class to create documents for my company. There is an example style for a word document but it looks more complex as most headers/footers I have found till now to re-create in LaTeX (at least for me). The example looks like the attached picture. I tried to play with `fancyhdr`, but didn't succeed with the problems: inserting the logo in a way that does not screw up the rest of the footer, aligning the text left and right, text above and under the line...

[image]

Comment: Looks like I'm not able to upload the image... you can find it [here](http://pics.vinno.be/latex-help)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)Please make sure that all images are uploaded using the official stackexchange interface, i.e. the image icon on top of the text field (shortcut: CTRL+G). This ensures that all images are always accessible and do not expire. As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have done with `fancyhdr` so far. Otherwise, your question may be interpreted as a typical "do-this-for-me-please-thanks".

Comment: just a suggested direction: create two minipages with the same height (that of the logo), flush the text content left and right in the other minipage, which is explicitly given the desired width, and use a vertical fill at top and bottom to center it.  then just set them side by side in a single "line".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my take at it. It is not well defined but sort of does what you are looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\footskip=70pt
\def\companylogo{\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
\fancypagestyle{companypagestyle}
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[L]
    {
        \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.5cm\relax}
        {
            \sffamily \bfseries\hfill MyCompany, MyStreet 1\\
            Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}\hfill 1234 City, Country\\
            {\color{red}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth\relax}{0.4pt}}\\
            www.mycompany.com
        }
    }
    \fancyfoot[R]
    {
        \parbox[b]{2cm}{\companylogo}%
    }
}

\pagestyle{companypagestyle}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I missed parbox. Thx

Comment: @lovebug356 You are welcome. It would be nice if you provide a MWE. It helps us know what style you want to work with, geometry of the page, class of document etc.

Answer (score 11):

Here's another possibility, using this time the [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package; using this package you can place the structure at any desired location on the pages of your documents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\backgroundsetup{
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  opacity=1,
  angle=0,
  position=current page.south,
  vshift=60pt,
  contents={%
  \small\sffamily%
  \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
  \parbox[b]{.6\textwidth}{%
    Page \thepage\ of   \pageref{LastPage}}\hfill
  \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{%
    \raggedleft My Company, My street 1 \\ 1234 city, Country}\\
  \textcolor{red}{\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}\\
  \url{www.mycompany.com}
  \end{minipage}\hspace{.02\textwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{.18\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=70pt,keepaspectratio]{ctanlion}
  \end{minipage}%
  }
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Am image of the first two pages:

[image]

And a zoom to the bottom of one of the pages:

[image]

CTAN lion draw­ing by Duane Bibby; thanks to www.ctan.org